# How to read laravel session last_activity value

Tags: laravel, session

I'm saving sessions to database and i have such value in my `last_activity` column

```
1538969099
```

Seriously what is this? I cannot understand it,

1. It's not today date
2. It's not current time (hour,minute,second)
3. I cannot use carbon format on it.

How should I use this in human language?

```
//controller
    $session = DB::table('sessions')->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
//blade
    @foreach($session as $sesh)
      {{$sesh->last_activity}} <br>
    @endforeach
```

Any idea?

Comment: It's unix timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Carbon::createFromTimestamp` or `new Date(timestamp)` in js

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it with **PHP** function `date`:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1538969099)
"2018-10-08 03:24:59"
```

Or `gmdate`:

```
gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", 1538969099)
"2018-10-08T03:24:59Z"
```

More information about `gmdate` is available [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php).

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading `Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler` where you can find this:

```
protected function getDefaultPayload($data)
{

    $payload = [
                'payload' => base64_encode($data),
                'last_activity' => $this->currentTime(),
            ];
```

the method `currentTime()` is implemented on the trait `Illuminate\Support\InteractsWithTime` which does that:

```
protected function currentTime()
{
    return Carbon::now()->getTimestamp();
}
```